# mapview doesn't show multipolygons of a query from osmdata

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-mapview

I am using the `osmdata` package to bring the universities of Bogota, some of these are mapped as `multipolygons`. However the plot comes out empty. Any idea how to fix it?

```
library(osmdata)
library(mapview)
query <- opq(bbox = "Bogota") %>% add_osm_feature(key = "amenity",value = "university") %>% osmdata_sf()
mapview(query$osm_multipolygons[,c("osm_id","name","amenity")], map.types = "OpenStreetMap")
#mapview(query$osm_polygons[,c("osm_id","name","amenity")], map.types = "OpenStreetMap")
```

**Note:** when plotting the points or polygons it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make a transformation to the object's coordinate system. As it's shown in the following:

```
library(osmdata)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
query <- opq(bbox = "Bogota") %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "amenity",value = "university") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

query <- query$osm_multipolygons[,c("osm_id","name","amenity")] %>%
  st_transform(st_crs("+proj=utm +ellps=GRS80 +datum=WGS84")) %>% 
  st_make_valid() 

mapview(query, map.types = "OpenStreetMap")
```

[image]

For more information check the following link. [Coordinate Systems in R](https://mgimond.github.io/Spatial/coordinate-systems-in-r.html)